# Runserver python django error

Tags: python, django-models, server, django-views

I'm trying to run a django application using `runserver` and am getting an error.

`python manage.py runserver 8009`

Here is the output:

```
Performing system checks...

    System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 04, 2018 - 02:48:59
Django version 2.0.2, using settings 'hesab.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x03E9F348>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sarvit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 13, in import_string
    module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit('.', 1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I have tried to `runserver` on port 8000 as well, and same error.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Cross check your main urls.py file. may get solution.